# Trouble with Angular Drag and Drop

Tags: html, angular, object, drag-and-drop, frontend

I'm trying to make it so a User has a page where they view their company cards. I want to be able to create containers or just some sorting objects that they can use to organize them.
I created an ng-expansion panel that I want it to be based on. However, I'm having trouble making a proper Drag and Drop to work between them.
I've been using the cdkDragDrop tool and I only managed to make the company cards themselves be drag and dropped on screen but not on the container. I can't seem to be able to make the proper connection, the Angular website cdk page only seems to want to drag and drop sentences, I can't find a way to rework it to drag and drop my cards instead.

My expansion-panel is written like this:

```
    <mat-expansion-panel cdkDropList (opened)="panelOpenState = true" (closed)="panelOpenState = false" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                Group Name
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>
                Currently I am {{panelOpenState ? 'open' : 'closed'}}
            </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
```

and my cards are formatted to where I called the drag and drop here:

```
<div cdkDropList class="d-flex align-content-start flex-wrap mt-4" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" *ngIf="!isLoading">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let perspective of watchlist">
                <div class="watchlist-card" cdkDrag>
                    <div class="watchlist-card-content">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column watchlist-card-body">
                            <!-- CARD HEADER AND REMOVE ICON -->
                            <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
                                <p class="card-title">{{ perspective.company.title }}</p>
                                <button class="button-icon" (click)="removeCompanyFromWatchlist(perspective)">
                                    <mat-icon class="btn-close">close</mat-icon>
                                </button>
                            </div>

                            <!-- 3P-SCORE -->
                            <ng-container *ngIf="scoreExists(perspective.company.scores) === true">
                                <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                                    <!-- 3P SCORE HEADER -->
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
                                        <p class="text-header">3P Score</p>
                                        <!-- TOTAL 3P SCORE -->
                                        <p class="text-header"> {{ calculateTotal3PScore(perspective.company.scores)}}/100</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- SCORE BREAKDOWN: People, Product & Performance -->
                                    <ng-container *ngFor="let criteria of scoreCriteria">
                                        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                                            <!-- SCORE CRITERIA & SCORE OUT OF 100 -->
                                            <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
                                                <div class="d-flex flex-row jutify-content-start align-self-center">
                                                    <img src={{criteria.icon}} class="score-icon">
                                                    <p class="score-label align-self-center">{{criteria.label | titlecase}}</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <p class="score-label">{{ perspective.company.scores[0][criteria.label] }}/100
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- PROGRESS BAR FOR CRITERIA -->
                                            <div class="d-flex flex-row jutify-content-start slider-bottom">
                                                <div class="slider-top"
                                                    [ngStyle]="{width: perspective.company.scores[0][criteria.label]+ '%'}">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </ng-container>
                                </div>
                            </ng-container>

                            <!-- NO 3P SCORE EXISTS -->
                            <ng-container *ngIf="scoreExists(perspective.company.scores) === false">
                                <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                                    <p class="text-header">3P Score</p>
                                    <p class="text-body">We don't have the 3P score of this input as of now. You can request the
                                        score and we will get back to you if it’s a
                                        company.</p>
                                    <button class="btn port-btn small-label" *ngIf="!perspective.company.score_requested"
                                        (click)="request3PScore(perspective)">Request 3P Score</button>
                                    <p class="text-body port-orange" *ngIf="perspective.company.score_requested"><b>Your request
                                            has been registered. We'll get back you to shortly.</b></p>
                                </div>
                            </ng-container>
    
                            <!-- FOOTER: KEWORDS AND ADD BUTTON -->
                            <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-auto">
                                <!-- KEYWORD CHIPS -->
                                <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap watchlist-keywords mt-2 mb-1">
                                    <mat-chip *ngFor="let keyword of perspective.keywords" class="keyword-chip mr-2" [removable]="removable"
                                        (removed)="removeKeywordFromWatchlist(perspective.keywords, keyword, perspective.id)">
                                        {{ keyword }}
                                        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">close</mat-icon>
                                    </mat-chip>
                                </div>
                                <!-- ADD KEYWORD BUTTON -->
                                <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-fill mr-auto mt-auto">
                                    <!-- INPUT FIELD FOR ADDING KEYWORDS -->
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-fill justify-content-between align-items-center" *ngIf="perspective.activeAddKeyword">
                                        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center search-bar p-3">
                                            <input [(ngModel)]="keywordInput" type="text" placeholder="Add keyword here" 
                                                (keyup.enter)="addKeywordToWatchlist(perspective.keywords, perspective.id)">
                                            <mat-icon matSuffix type="submit" (click)="addKeywordToWatchlist(perspective.keywords, perspective.id)">add</mat-icon>
                                        </div>
                                        <button class="button-curved ml-2 p-1" *ngIf="perspective.activeAddKeyword"
                                            (click)="closeAddKeywordInput(perspective)">
                                            Cancel
                                        </button>
                                    </div>

                                    <button class="button-icon button-raised mt-auto" *ngIf="!perspective.activeAddKeyword" (click)="showAddKeywordInput(perspective)">
                                        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-handle" cdkDragHandle>
                                    <svg width="24px" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                        <path
                                            d="M10 9h4V6h3l-5-5-5 5h3v3zm-1 1H6V7l-5 5 5 5v-3h3v-4zm14 2l-5-5v3h-3v4h3v3l5-5zm-9 3h-4v3H7l5 5 5-5h-3v-3z">
                                        </path>
                                        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
```

*The rest of the card setups follows, this is just where I just the cdkDrag*

*Edit, fixed up the cdkDropList as suggested by one of the answers.
*Edit2, Showed the whole card code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angular material Drag&Drop works with the concept of lists.
What you can do is connect lists (Drag and drop, or within the same list, or to another list).

So, let's assume, that the expansion panel is a list (It is a list because if you can drag things there, for Angular Material Drag & Drop it is a list)

To connect your expansion panel with cards that are not in there. You are going to have and keep two arrays. The first contain all your cards, and the second contain the cards that are inside the expansion panel

In your expansion panel:

```
<mat-expansion-panel
         cdkDropList
         #expansionPanelList="cdkDropList"
         [cdkDropListData]="arrayCardsInsideExpansion"
         [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[listOfAllCards]"
         (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
         (opened)="panelOpenState = true" 
         (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
            Group Name
        </mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description>
            Currently I am {{panelOpenState ? 'open' : 'closed'}}
        </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let perspective of arrayCardsInsideExpansion">
        <div class="watchlist-card" cdkDrag>
                   .
                   .
                   .
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

And your cards:

```
<div cdkDropList 
     #listOfAllCards="cdkDropList"
     [cdkDropListData]="watchlist"
     [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[expansionPanelList]"
     class="d-flex align-content-start flex-wrap mt-4" 
     (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let perspective of watchlist">
                <div class="watchlist-card" cdkDrag>
                   .
                   .
                   .
```

Finally in your .ts Code, your drop Function:

```
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
  .
  .
  .
  .
 drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                        event.container.data,
                        event.previousIndex,
                        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

If you have a lot of expansion panel, check [CdkDropListGroup](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDropListGroup)

Comment: You code is fine. Try to reload vsCode, and restart angular server. What is your Angular version?. And the angular material?. –

Comment: I tried closing and restarting the server, it's still not working and giving me the error of `Property 'listOfAllCards' does not exist on type 'WatchlistComponent'`  my angular version is Angular CLI: 9.1.12 and no, it's just single expansion panel. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: When I run the server, the drag works and looks like it is going to drop into the expansion panel, but when I actually let go, it disappears. That's probably part of the error of listofAllcards

Comment: console says: Uncaught Error: cdkDrag must be attached to an element node. Currently attached to "#comment".
    at CdkDrag._updateRootElement (drag-drop.js:4710)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (drag-drop.js:4615)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at TakeUntilSubscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at TakeUntilSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at TakeSubscriber._next (take.js:35)
    at TakeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)`

Comment: *ngIf="!isLoading" is killing the connection, remove please and try

Comment: Okay, the error about listofAllcards is gone, but the server is still acting weird, it's not registering the cards inside the expansion-panel when I drag it, it just disappears and gives the same error on the console.

Comment: Uncaught Error: cdkDrag must be attached to an element node. Currently attached to "#comment".
    at CdkDrag._updateRootElement (drag-drop.js:4710)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (drag-drop.js:4615)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at TakeUntilSubscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at TakeUntilSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at TakeSubscriber._next (take.js:35)
    at TakeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)

Comment: change this part:
   <ng-container *ngFor="let cards of arrayCardsInsideExpansion" cdkDrag>
      </ng-container>

for

   <div *ngFor="let cards of arrayCardsInsideExpansion" cdkDrag>
      </div>

Comment: Do you think If I tried a different container besides an expansion panel, it might work?

Comment: No, it is the same. Expansion panel In the background, it is a div. The error ocurrs, because cdkDrag need an element, and ng-container is not an element. My mistake

Comment: Okay, there are no errors in the server or the console, but the cards aren't showing in the expansion panel, they just get dragged in and disappear. The console shows that they are indeed inside of it, but they aren't showing.

Comment: You must to repeat the entire code of your cards inside <div *ngFor="let cards of arrayCardsInsideExpansion" cdkDrag> //All your card code  </div>

I assumed it was clear. Sorry.

That is why it is very important to see the entire code.

Next time if you can, upload the code to stackblitz.com so we are not correcting errors on the fly.

however, a pleasure to help you. With that it will stay working.

Good night and don't forget my ice cream!

Comment: I recommend you create a component only for the card so as not to repeat so much code

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I hope you like Pistachio Ice Cream! Seriously though, I appreciate it and I would definitely experiment and put it in its own component to make it smaller. Ill also definitely try out stackblitz.com. Good Night to you too!